# Dictionary objects function Exists adding not existing key to dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

```
Sub test()
    Dim authDict As Dictionary
    Set authDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    authDict.Add "Anton", 1
    authDict.Add "Martin", "3"
    authDict.Add "Dave", 1

    testKey = authDict.Exists("Alina") ' False, but adding this Key to dictionary by itself
    testVal = authDict("Alina")
    testKey2 = authDict.Exists("Alina") ' now it true
    testVal2 = authDict("Alina")
End Sub
```

Why after not exists state dictionary adding this key to dictionary by themselves? How to prevent this

Comment: I think by using the line `testVal = authDict("Alina")` , it adds to the dictionary.

Comment: To avoid this behavior, you'll have to use a custom Dictionary like this one: https://gist.github.com/florentbr/12c90342af901b39350eaee6a72bed3d#file-4-dictionary-cls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that this line

```
testVal = authDict("Alina")
```

will add the item `Alina` to the dictionary. So you should only run it if it already exists, otherwise it will be created. Use the `Exists()` method for this like below:

```
If authDict.Exists("Alina") Then ' False, but adding this Key to dictionary by itself
    testVal = authDict("Alina")
Else
    MsgBox "Alina does not exist"
End If
```

#### Why?

By using `authDict("Alina")` you use the [Item property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/item-property-dictionary-object) of the [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) submitting `Alina` as parameter `key`.

So according to the documentation the item property *"Sets or returns an item for a specified key in a Dictionary object."*. Since `Alina` doesn't exist yet there is nothing to return, so it sets it by default.

The documentation of the item property furthermore says:

> *If key is not found when changing an item, a new key is created with the specified newitem. If key is not found when attempting to return an existing item, a new key is created and its corresponding item is left empty.*

*<sup>Source: [Item property section Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/item-property-dictionary-object#remarks).</sup>*

Comment: My question was - WHY?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin by design. Microsoft coded it that way. You must check if it exists otherwise it will be auto created. That's the default behaviour. There is no explanation to "Why" because it is just because Microsoft programmers chose it to be like that.

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin See my edited answer that now includes the answer to *"Why?"*.

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin As what was mentioned, it is how it's designed. See [Dictionary Documentation](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) clause 5.3 assigning it to a variable.